# Cyrillic transliteration in R

Tags: r, transliteration

Are there packages for Cyrillic text transliteration to Latin in R? I need to convert data frames to Latin to use factors. It is somewhat messy to use Cyrillic factors in R.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have found the package at last.

```
> library(stringi)
> stri_trans_general("женщина", "cyrillic-latin")
[1] "ženŝina"

> stri_trans_general("женщина", "russian-latin/bgn")
[1] "zhenshchina"
```

After that, the only issue remaining is the "ё" letter.

```
> stri_trans_general("Ёж", "russian-latin/bgn")
[1] "Yëzh"

> stri_trans_general("подъезд", "russian-latin/bgn")
[1] "podʺyezd"

> stri_trans_general("мальчик", "russian-latin/bgn")
[1] "malʹchik"
```

I had to remove all the "ё", "ʹ" and "ʺ" characters

```
> iconv(stri_trans_general("ёж", "russian-latin/bgn"),from="UTF8",to="ASCII",sub="")
[1] "yzh"
```

Or one can just remove the 'Ё' and 'ё' letters before

```
> gsub('ё','e',gsub('Ё','E','Ёжики на ёлке'))
[1] "Eжики на eлке"
```

or after transliteration.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to do it with stringi package as you above, but with different transform identifier, for Serbian latin:

```
`stri_trans_general("жшчћђ", "Serbian-Latin/BGN")`
```

All characters should be transformed correctly to Serbian latin.

Answer (score 1):

If afterwards one uses **Base R** to filter the data in Cyrillic, one get's all **NA's**, but if **dplyr** is used then everything is fine.